# Concurrency Bot state in Dialog Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, botframework

I'm building a Bot which uses dialog to interact with the client and right now, I'm using the **PrivateConversationData** in the **IDialogContext** to store some parameters of an Client when they start chatting with my Bot. However, as I've read the [User State Document](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/userdata/#navtitle), they've said:

> The maximum amount of data that you can store in each store for a user or conversation is 32 KB. For example, you can store 32 KB of data for User A on channel ABC, 32 KB of data for User A in a private conversation on channel ABC, and 32 KB of data for Conversation 1 on channel ABC.

So what happen if many client chat with my Bot at the same time and my code store some parameters to query my Database, will my data be lost if the next client communicates with my bot and set some parameters with the same name, too? I've confused that whether each client chat with the bot will have their own **PrivateConversationData** or all clients connect with the Bot will access the only one **PrivateConversationData**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrivateConversationData` store is unique for the key user + conversation, so no, your clients won't access to only one `PrivateConversationData`.

> If you want to save state data for a user on a channel that IS specific to a conversation, use the Private Conversation data store

However, based on your writing, it seems that using `UserData` store in your case would be better as the data you are storing in the data bags seems not specific to a conversation.

> If you want to save state data for a user on a channel that is NOT specific to a conversation, use the User Data store

Take a look to the [State sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State) to review this concepts. Also, if you want to use a custom storage for the state, review the [Custom State](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-CustomState) sample.

Comment: actually, my case here is that each users will need to query some specific data that may not the same for all users, so I think using private is suitable.

Comment: Finally, is it true that if the first bot instance set some value, the next won't change it if it's the same parameter key?

Comment: User data is private to the user, it's not shared with other users, that's why is better for your scenario. Is the same that private conversation data but without the conversation context. It won't change,  it's s per user talking to the bot. Private conversation is useful if for the same user you will have different data iin multiple conversations with the bot (for the same user)

Comment: FYI - I added links to some samples around state that you might find useful.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help! It supports me lots.